# Sum of Array using for loop returning 0

Tags: java

I have written this code below which should return the sum of an array. But it keeps returning 0. Please can someone help with this?

```
public class sumArray {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println(sumArrayof());
    }

    public static int sumArrayof(){
        int k;
        int sum = 0;
        int[] bs = new int[20];

        for (k=0; k<bs.length; k++) {

            sum = sum + bs[k];

        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, you're creating a new array of 20 integers, each of which is 0, and then summing those zeroes... where did you expect the data to come from?

Comment: (Additionally, please put more effort into formatting your code. Look at the preview before you post.)

Comment: Uhhhh.. What are you adding .. You are just summing up `bs[0]+bs[1]...+b[19]` which are all 0. The sum is supposed to 0.

Comment: Do you want sum of 0 to 20 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should receive an array as a parameter, instead of generating an array itself.

Like this:

```
public static int sumArrayof(int[] data) {
    int k;
    int sum = 0;   
    for (k=0; k<data.length; k++) {
        sum = sum + data[k];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class, as written, isn't useful.

The method returns a zero because you're summing an array that has all zeroes in it.  It's doing exactly what you asked it to do.

Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
public class ArrayUtils {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            int [] values = new int[args.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
                values[i] = Integer.parseInt(arg);
            }
            System.out.println(ArrayUtils.sum(values));
        }
    }

    public static int sum(int [] values) {
        int sum = 0;
        if (values != null) {
            for (int value : values) { 
                sum += value;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: good answer for a good question sir. your 190k is well deserved.

Answer (score 0):

It is as expected.

You have made an empty array

```
int[] bs = new int[20]; 

// as good as
// int[] bs = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

which contains only zeroes.

Hence `sum = 0`

To fix you initialize array with initial values for eg

```
int[] bs = {1, 2, 3, 4 .......................};
```

Answer (score 0):

Int array is only initialized. So default value is populated. So All the 20 elements are 0 only. So Iterating and adding 20 zero elements. So result is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is full of zeros.
Try something like that:

```
int[] bs = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

or initialize it some other way (like in another loop) or get it from main method input args.

Answer (score 0):

Your array consists of 20 integers, but you never initialize them so they are 0.

```
int[] bs = new int[20];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bs)); // <-- 20 0s.
for (k=0; k<bs.length; k++) {
  sum = sum + bs[k];
}
return sum;
```

`20 * 0` **is** 0.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fill this array with some data.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before you need to assign values to your array before summing them up. 
You could do this: ps:altough you probably want to assign more meaningfull numbers ;) :

```
Random random = new Random();

public int getSomeValue(){
    return random.nextInt(); // your logic to get a value 
}

for (k=0; k<bs.length; k++) {

    bs[k] = getSomeValue();

}

for (k=0; k<bs.length; k++) {

    sum = sum + bs[k];

}
```